# RingtoneManager not showing all available ringtones

Tags: android, android-intent, startactivityforresult

I want to pick ringtone from my android app. For that purpose I used the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select ringtone:");
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
```

My issue is, in Lollipop devices it doesn't show all the ringtone files. There are a lot of files in the external sd card but it is not listed in the ringtone picker. I tested it on jelly bean devices and it is working perfectly. Please help me, how can I make it work in Android L devices ?

Comment: It's 2020. Android Q. I am sure this must have been resolved with some small fix, can you please share the solution?

Comment: @sud007 The newer versions it's working fine, but in some handset models the default ringtone manager won't show these files (but choosing a different app (file explorers) fixed the issue )

Comment: Actually I tried using the `ContentResolver` way of fetching files from the system, both internal and external storage, but it fails to give the count of items I have recently downloaded. In my case However I can not use the FileExplorer Picker. Thanks for the response. Much appreciated! If there is any other path, let me know.

Comment: @sud007: Sure, I'll let you know if I find something. Thanks for your comment :)